# How to format a tupled list in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, format

I asked a previous question here and got a great answer: How to assign items in nested lists a variable automatically in Python 2.7? to do the following when it came to putting up an output:

Previous Question:

```
nList = [[0,0,0],[3,2,1]],\ [[]],\ [[100,1000,110]],\ [[0,0,0],[300,400,300],[300,400,720],[0,0,120],[100,0,1320],[30,500,1450]]
```

> I need to assign automatic variables to the items before each '\'. for
>   example, distance1 = [[0,0,0],[3,2,1]], distance2=[[]], distance3=
>   [[100,1000,110]] etc. However, this needs to be automatic for each
>   distance'n' rather than me taking indexes from mList and assigning
>   them to variable distance'n

Now, I need to format the distanceN variables so that trying to print distance4 for example would give the output:

```
>>0 metres, 0 metres, 0 seconds
>>300 metres, 400 metres, 300 seconds
>>300 metres, 400 metres, 720 seconds
>>0 metres, 0 metres, 120 seconds
>>100 metres, 0 metres, 1320 seconds
>>30 metres, 500 metres, 1450 seconds
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The answer you got was not very good. You already know how to use format so you should be able to use that to do what you want. Read the documentation for str.format.

Comment: The answer you got was awful. The answer you *should* have gotten is that your `mList` variable already did everything your numbered variables would have done, but better. In particular, modifications to `locals` usually don't actually do anything to a function's local variables!

Comment: That was me who gave the bad answer, and I've updated my previous answer to remove the offending part... I did also suggest that if the OP needs to refer to different parts of mList by name to use a dictionary e.g. dist['distance1'] == mlist[0]

Comment: Thanks @achampion and others for your help. I am really new to programming and trying to sort out how to solve problems that seem very complex to me right now so might even be deciphering answers wrongly and I apologise for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert `nList` into anything; not into named variables, not into a dictionary. It works fine as a tuple (incidentally it is *not* a list - it is a tuple of lists). You could name it `distances` instead.

```
distances = [[0,0,0],[3,2,1]], [[]], [[100,1000,110]], [[0,0,0],[300,400,300],[300,400,720],[0,0,120],[100,0,1320],[30,500,1450]]

# "distance4" accessed by index 3 in tuple
for distance in distances[3]:
    print '{} metres, {} metres, {} seconds'.format(*distance)
```

**Output**

```
0 metres, 0 metres, 0 seconds
300 metres, 400 metres, 300 seconds
300 metres, 400 metres, 720 seconds
0 metres, 0 metres, 120 seconds
100 metres, 0 metres, 1320 seconds
30 metres, 500 metres, 1450 seconds
```

Comment: Hi @mhawke. Thanks for the answer! The exact program I am trying to write is that if a user types 'print distance1', the program needs to be flexible and produce <br> 0 metres, 0 metres, 0 seconds</br><br>3 metres, 2 metres, 1 seconds and so on for distance2, distance3, distance4. So, how do I write the program in for distance in distances[''] where the distance can be an integer of the users choosing?